# Uploading file with Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Im currently having a lot of trouble when it comes to this one. I've tried to using [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) but turns out it giving me error which i do not understand.

**Error**

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for TaskComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
noComponentFactoryError@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:3565:34 [angular]
```

It gave me `No component factory found for TaskComponent` error. This is only comes up when i have a `@Directive` inside my component.

**Edited TaskComponent.ts**

```
import { Directive, Component, OnInit,  OnDestroy, ViewChild, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal/modal.component';

import { ApiService } from '../../assets/services/api.service';

import { UploadOutput, UploadInput, UploadFile, humanizeBytes } from 'ngx-uploader';

// class FileSelectDirective
@Directive({ selector: '[ng2FileSelect]' })

@Component({
            selector: 'app-task',
            templateUrl: './task.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['./task.component.scss']
})
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit(){}
}
```

I have also imported this into my module.

**RtoModule.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal';
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';

import { TaskComponent } from '../task/task.component';
import { TaskDetailsComponent } from '../task-details/task-details.component';

import { RtoRoutingModule } from '../rto-routing/rto-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RtoRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    TaskComponent,
    TaskDetailsComponent
  ]
})
export class RtoModule { }
```

Could someone point me out where did i do wrong? Wherever in the implementation or any.

Thank you in advance!

PS: Im currently using Angular4 version in this project

Comment: Do you have an exported class in `TaskComponent.ts`?

Comment: I have edited my code. @OmriLuzon

Comment: Try to add this line after declarations array: entryComponents: [TaskComponent]

Comment: Your component seems to be declared as `TaskComponent implements OnInit`, but doesn't have `ngOnInit` function in it. (this should give you some other error, but still)

Comment: I have tried to declare TaskComponent in entryComponents, but it gave me another error which said `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: TaskComponent cannot be used as an entry component.
syntaxError@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:39555:34 [angular]` @BlackEagle

Comment: Ah yes, regarding that i have ngOnInit on my actual code. I will edit the code here in my question that will not give confusion to anyone @OmriLuzon

Comment: why do u declaring "@Directive({ selector: '[ng2FileSelect]' })"? ng2FileSelectdirective is already declared in ng2-file-upload?

Comment: Hmm actually im a bit confused, thats why i asked can someone point me out where im wrong implementing the `ng2-file-upload` @JuliaPassynkova

Comment: i need to see the whole solution to help. i use ng2-file-upload in my projects. also it is very confusing why do u import from ngx-uploader? it is another file upload library.

Comment: I've tried also with ngx-uploader before this. So that should explain why it was there

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova I've implement the backend code in nodejs which is from [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/blob/development/demo/server/file-catcher.js). It gives `TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions`. Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i mad a mistake on implementing this module.

Somehow now it works, no errors on my component.
I implement these codes on my component

```
  public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});
  public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
  public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
```

Now it seems to be working correctly. Currently im developing the backend.

Thank you for all who has reponded to my question!